# Create route collection (or similar) for hierarchical page structure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry if the question seems complicated but, in a typical CMS, the pages will have a hierarchical structure. In other words, you would create top level pages, and those pages would have children, those pages would have children etc etc

I'm writing a small CMS at work, in MVC3, which needs to be able interpret URLs which reflect this hierarchical nature. Eg:

```
http://mysite/page1/page1.1/page1.1.1/page1.1.1.1
```

I've current got a "catchall" set up in the routing and I'm matching the incoming url to the page entity via the controller / view model. It seems a bit clunky and resource-intensive.

Is anybody aware of a way of handling this via routing? I can't seem to find the answer, there may not be one!

Thanks..

**EDIT**

Figured something out - registered a route for each url in the Global.asax using the page data in the db and recursion. Still feels a bit clunky though...

Comment: Coul you please elaborate on what you have done . It night help me with my problem. ThX

Comment: Register a route for each url - so in global.asax, at some point (either at every page request or on a timer?) interrogate your DB, iterate through each existing url, and register a route for it. Not sure it's a great method though..